# C: Logical operators

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

In this code, the user must type his/her grade (1-10) on a subject and his/her absences(0-14) on it. If he/she gets >=5 grade and <=2 absences, the student passes.

I have a problem with the possibility that both grade and absences numbers are off the limits of the programme. Which are the "right" logical operators on this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{   
    int gr, ap;

    printf("GIVE YOUR SUBJECT GRADE:\n");
    scanf("%d", &gr);
    printf("GIVE YOUR SUBJECT ABSENCES\n");
    scanf("%d", &ap);

    if (ap >= 0 && ap <= 14 && gr >= 0 && gr <= 10)
    {
       if (gr >= 5 && ap <= 2)
          printf("YOU PASSED!\n");
       else if (gr < 5 && ap <=2)
          printf("FAILED DUE TO YOUR GRADE\n");
       else if (gr >= 5 && ap > 2)
          printf("FAILED DUE TO YOUR ABSENCES\n");
       else if (gr < 5 && ap > 2)
          printf("FAILED DUE TO YOUR GRADE AND ABSENCES\n");   
    }
    else 
     {                    
        if (ap >= 0 && ap <= 14 && gr < 0 || gr > 10)  
             printf("FALSE GRADE NUMBER\n");       
        else if (gr >= 0 && gr <= 10 && ap < 0 || ap > 14)
             printf("FALSE ABSENCES NUMBER\n");
//here is the problem
        else if (gr < 0 || gr > 10 && ap < 0 || ap > 14) 
             printf("FALSE ABSENCES AND GRADE NUMBERS\n");
      }     
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `&&` has priority over `||`, you need parentheses here:

```
ap >= 0 && ap <= 14 && (gr < 0 || gr > 10)
//                     ^                 ^
```

Otherwise, the condition is interpreted as

```
(ap >= 0 && ap <= 14 && gr < 0) || (gr > 10)
```

which causes issues down the line.

Same goes for the other two conditions - they should be as follows:

```
(gr >= 0 && gr <= 10) && (ap < 0 || ap > 14)
(gr < 0 || gr > 10) && (ap < 0 || ap > 14)
```

Note that when you keep evaluating the same conditions over and over it is better to make a variable that stores their result once, and use that variable after that:

```
int validGrade = gr > 0 && gr <= 10;
int validAbsences = ap >= 0 && ap < 14;
```

Now you can write code like this:

```
if (validGrade && validAbsences) {
    ...
} else {
    if (validAbsences && !validGrade) {
        ...
    } else if (!validAbsences && validGrade) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first check if `gr` is out of range but not `ap`, then you check if `ap` is out of range but not `gr`, and if neither of them is true then both must be out of range, and for that you only need an `else` statement last.

However, the two conditions above are wrong, change the `||` to `&&`. In fact, you don't really check both `ap` and `gr`, because if one is in range you know the other is out of range. So you can simplify it like this:

```
// If ap is in range, that means gr must be out of range
if (ap >= 0 && ap <= 14)
    printf("FALSE GRADE NUMBER\n");
// else if gr is in range then ap must be out of range
else if (gr >= 0 && gr <= 10)
    printf("FALSE ABSENCES NUMBER\n");
// else both ap and gr are out of range
else
    printf("FALSE ABSENCES AND GRADE NUMBERS\n");
```

---

I also have another couple of suggestions, like using `unsigned int` instead, then the value can never be below zero. You could also use macros to ease maintainability and readability of the code.

Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define AP_IN_RANGE(ap)  ((ap) <= 14)
#define GR_IN_RANGE(gr)  ((gr) <= 10)

int main(void)
{   
    unsigned int gr, ap;

    printf("GIVE YOUR SUBJECT GRADE:\n");
    scanf("%u", &gr);
    printf("GIVE YOUR SUBJECT ABSENCES\n");
    scanf("%u", &ap);

    if (AP_IN_RANGE(ap) && GR_IN_RANGE(gr))
    {
       if (gr >= 5 && ap <= 2)
          printf("YOU PASSED!\n");
       else if (gr < 5 && ap <=2)
          printf("FAILED DUE TO YOUR GRADE\n");
       else if (gr >= 5 && ap > 2)
          printf("FAILED DUE TO YOUR ABSENCES\n");
       else
          printf("FAILED DUE TO YOUR GRADE AND ABSENCES\n");   
    }
    else
    {                    
        if (AP_IN_RANGE(ap))
            printf("FALSE GRADE NUMBER\n");       
        else if (GR_IN_RANGE(gr))
            printf("FALSE ABSENCES NUMBER\n");
        else
            printf("FALSE ABSENCES AND GRADE NUMBERS\n");
    }     
}
```

Of course, you should really make sure that the user input if valid, so you need to check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns. This will protect against the user inputting some letters instead of a valid unsigned number.